# Trying to access string in struct causes segmentation fault

Tags: c, struct

It's my first time posting a question here and i'll try to be as precise as I can.So i have this project and when i try to access a string in a struct it gives me a segmentation fault.

```
struct InfoSession {
TabNodePtr FirstTab;
TabNodePtr LastTab;
TabNodePtr CurrTab;
TabNodePtr AuxTab;
char*     OpeningAddress;};
```

this is the struct included in the Session.c file where i have all the functions that i want to call in my main.

```
void SessionNewOpeningAddress(char * OpeningAddress,InfoSessionPtr Session){
scanf("%s",&OpeningAddress);
strcpy(Session->OpeningAddress,OpeningAddress);}
```

this is one of the functions that cause a segmentation fault(after testing i realised that each function that calls `Session->OpeningAddress`cause a segmentation fault.)This is my main.c where my main is included.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "Session.h"



int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   InfoSessionPtr   MySession=NULL;
   int option;
   char OpeningAddress;


do{

    printf("\n\n1. Create Session.\n\
    2. Create new tab.\n\
    3. Go to next tab.\n\
    4. Go to previous tab.\n\
    5. Move tab left.\n\
    6. Move tab right.\n\
    7. Set new opening address.\n\
    8. Show the default opening address.\n\
    9. Go to next site.\n\
    10.Go to previous site.\n\
    11.Show the current address.\n\
    12.Close the current tab.\n\
    13.Close session.\n\
    14.Open a new address.\n\
    Dwste thn epilogh sas(1-14, 0 gia eksodo):");

    scanf("%d",&option);
    switch(option)
    {case 1:
        SessionNew(&OpeningAddress);
        MySession =&SessionNew;
        printf("The Session has been created!");
        break;
     case 2:
        SessionNewTab(MySession);
        break;
     case 3:
        SessionTabNext(MySession);
        break;
     case 4:
        SessionTabPrev(MySession);
        break;
     case 5:
        SessionTabMoveLeft(MySession);
        break;
     case 6:
        SessionTabMoveRight(MySession);
        break;
     case 7:
        printf("Dwste nea dieuthinsi gia default\n");
        SessionNewOpeningAddress(&OpeningAddress,MySession);
        break;
     case 8:
        SessionShowOpeningAddress(MySession);
        break;
     case 9:
        SessionSiteNext(MySession);
        break;
     case 10:
        SessionSitePrev(MySession);
        break;
     case 11:
        SessionAddressShow(MySession);
        break;
     case 12:
        SessionTabClose(MySession);
        break;
     case 13:
        SessionClose(MySession);
        break;
     case 14:
        SessionNewAddress(&OpeningAddress,MySession);
        break;
    }
}while(option); 

return 0;}
```

I've searched all over the internet but i still cant understand where the problem is.Anyone that can help me please reply as fast as you can.
Oh and the SessionNew function is here(everything works fine in this function):

```
InfoSessionPtr SessionNew(char * OpeningAddress){
TabNodePtr Tab;
InfoSessionPtr IS;
SiteNodePtr Site;
IS=malloc(sizeof(struct InfoSession));
Tab=malloc(sizeof(struct TabNode));
Site=malloc(sizeof(struct SiteNode));
IS->OpeningAddress=malloc(strlen(OpeningAddress)+1);
Site->Address=malloc(strlen(OpeningAddress)+1);
IS->AuxTab = NULL;
IS->CurrTab = Tab;
IS->FirstTab = Tab;
IS->LastTab = Tab;
Tab->NextTab = Tab;
Tab->PrevTab = Tab;
Site->UpTab = Tab;
Tab->CurrSite = Site;
Tab->FirstSite = Site;
OpeningAddress = "google";
strcpy(IS->OpeningAddress,OpeningAddress);
strcpy(Site->Address,IS->OpeningAddress);}
```

Comment: `scanf("%s",&OpeningAddress);` inside the function  `void SessionNewOpeningAddress(char * OpeningAddress,InfoSessionPtr Session)` is wrong

Comment: the OpeningAddress in the scanf refers to the OpeningAddress of main.not to the OpeningAddress of struct.

Comment: The `char OpeningAddress;` variable declared in `main` means you only have room to store a single byte. If you want more, use an array and pass `OpeningAddress` to `SessionNewOpeningAddress`, not `&OpeningAddress`. You also need to change the `scanf("%s", &OpeningAddress)` to be `scanf("%s", OpeningAddress)`. If you want to be safe, which you should, also change `%s` in that to something like `%39s` if you used `char OpeningAddress[40];` (you have 40 bytes available, but your field width is 39 because of the null terminating byte that is automatically added by `scanf`).

Comment: I tried what you suggested but still did not work.As far as i tested with other functions the problem lies in `Session->OpeningAddress`

Comment: Memory for the OpeningAddress in the structure is allocated using malloc in the function SessionNew.I tried allocating space in the SessionNewOpeningAddress too but it did not work

Comment: You're also trying to `strcpy(Session->OpeningAddress, OpeningAddress);`, but it's not necessarily a guarantee that `Session->OpeningAddress` has enough memory allocated to store the `OpeningAddress`. You might have allocated 10 bytes in `SessionNew`, but if you read 15 bytes, plus the null terminator for a total of 16 bytes, then you can't fit those 16 bytes into 10 bytes, right? Also, you should ensure that `scanf` returned the number of conversion specifications you used: `if (scanf("%39s", OpeningAddress) != 1) { /* handle input error */ }`.

Comment: I've thought about that so i've been testing using only 1 character for input(for example g) but still no change.For testing purposes i put `Session->OpeningAddress` in another function that worked correctly without changing it's value.The function caused a segmention fault..

Comment: What happens when you use a debugger to step through the code, watching the value of `Session->OpeningAddress`? Did you compile with all warnings enabled? As xing mentioned, `MySession =&SessionNew` looks strange, and you should have assigned the return value of `SessionNew` to `MySession`, assuming you're returning `IS`.

Comment: Yep i always use `SessionNew` first. And the debugger did not say that it was null.

Comment: [C functions tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_functions.htm)

Comment: I think we are saying the same thing but because of my lack of knowledge I cant really explain it. what i meant is that `InfoSessionPtr SessionNew(char * OpeningAddress)` has that `InfoSessionPtr` in front so i said that it is defined as `InfoSessionPtr`.

Comment: it is still a char.check my above comment cause i edited it.firstly i did it like this `MySession = SessionNew(&OpeningAddress);` and it didnt crash ,then i saw that u did not include a & and changed it and it crashed when i called SessionNew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this. I moved the statement `OpeningAddress = "google";` before the malloc and changed it to strcpy. As I did nt have the session.h file and the other functions, i removed those references.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct InfoSession {
    char*     OpeningAddress;};

typedef struct InfoSession *InfoSessionPtr;

void SessionNewOpeningAddress(char * OpeningAddress,InfoSessionPtr Session){
    scanf("%39s",OpeningAddress);
    strcpy(Session->OpeningAddress,OpeningAddress);}

InfoSessionPtr SessionNew(char * OpeningAddress){
    InfoSessionPtr IS;
    IS=malloc(sizeof(struct InfoSession));

    strcpy ( OpeningAddress, "google");

    IS->OpeningAddress=malloc(strlen(OpeningAddress)+1);
    strcpy(IS->OpeningAddress,OpeningAddress);
    return IS;}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    InfoSessionPtr   MySession=NULL;
    int option;
    char OpeningAddress[40] = "g";


    do{

        printf("\n\n1. Create Session.\n\
        2. Create new tab.\n\
        3. Go to next tab.\n\
        4. Go to previous tab.\n\
        5. Move tab left.\n\
        6. Move tab right.\n\
        7. Set new opening address.\n\
        8. Show the default opening address.\n\
        9. Go to next site.\n\
        10.Go to previous site.\n\
        11.Show the current address.\n\
        12.Close the current tab.\n\
        13.Close session.\n\
        14.Open a new address.\n\
        Dwste thn epilogh sas(1-14, 0 gia eksodo):");

        scanf("%d",&option);
        switch(option)
        {case 1:
            MySession = SessionNew(OpeningAddress);
            printf("The Session has been created!");
                break;
            case 2:
                break;
            case 3:
                break;
            case 4:
                break;
            case 5:
                break;
            case 6:
                break;
            case 7:
                printf("Dwste nea dieuthinsi gia default\n");
                SessionNewOpeningAddress(OpeningAddress,MySession);
                break;
            case 8:
                break;
             case 9:
                break;          
             case 10:
                break;
            case 11:
                break;
            case 12:
                break;
            case 13:
                break;
            case 14:
                break;
        }
    }while(option); 

return 0;}
```